# Ruby on Rails: Why do I have to use sudo for commands to succede?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sudo, refinerycms

I'm learning ruby on rails... I've was able to install an app on my OSX (10.8.3) localhost but it was very problematic most commands failed with permission-related errors unless I used sudo:

`$ refinerycms ./`

`$ bundle install`

`$ bundle update`

`$ rails server`

All off these fail without `sudo...` and I'm not sure why. It's somewhat of a hassle to do, but more importantly it seems like I must have done something wrong during set-up for this to be happening. Does anyone know what I did wrong and how to fix it?

**Update** I suspect this might be relevant:
(Notice that *both* point to the same place.)

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/


$ sudo gem environment
Password:
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /Users/ESL/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

This may or may not be related to the fact that `~/.rvm` does not exist. It doesn't appear `.rvm` exists anywhere.

**Update 2** I don't know much about rails apps but I noticed that certain files appear to be owned by the system and not my user. Is that normal?

**Update 3** My hunch is that all my gems are associated with root, not my user, which would explain why I keep getting permissions errors every time I try to do things. So I tried reinstalling rvm as a user...

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    192      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   223
100 13641  100 13641    0     0   9060      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  9060
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124  100   124    0     0    381      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   475
100 3263k  100 3263k    0     0   536k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--  615k

Upgrading the RVM installation in /usr/local/rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/ESL/.bashrc /Users/ESL/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/ESL/.bash_profile /Users/ESL/.zprofile.

Upgrade Notes:


  * WARNING: you have 'rvm_configure_env' in /etc/rvmrc, run the following to fix:

      sudo sed -i'' -e "/rvm_configure_env=.*\/opt\/sm/d" /etc/rvmrc
      rvm autolibs smf

  * No new notes to display.

# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.io/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues run 'rvm requirements' or read 'rvm notes'

Upgrade of RVM in /usr/local/rvm/ is complete.

#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and
#   more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne

It seems to have worked, but it looks to me like it keeps landing in the root instead of /Users/ME. Am I onto something?
```

**update**

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    124      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   143
100 13641  100 13641    0     0   6907      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  6907
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124  100   124    0     0    561      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   712
100 3263k  100 3263k    0     0   767k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--  907k

Installing RVM to /usr/local/rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/ESL/.bashrc /Users/ESL/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/ESL/.bash_profile /Users/ESL/.zprofile.

# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.io/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues run 'rvm requirements' or read 'rvm notes'

Installation of RVM in /usr/local/rvm/ is almost complete:

  * First you need to add all users that will be using rvm to 'rvm' group,
    and logout - login again, anyone using rvm will be operating with `umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx`.

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and
#   more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne
```

Comment: what appears if you type in your console "which ruby" in your project folder? I think you are using the mac system ruby probably..

Comment: I get `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby` which is rvm right?

Comment: I don't know much about rails apps but I noticed that certain files appear to be owned by the system and not my user. Is that normal? Ex: `goodwatching/config/initializers/refinery/core.rb`

Comment: I'm a n00b at all of this, but I'm getting the sense that something must be installed in the wrong place (root instead of my user?). Maybe that explains why I need to use `sudo` for everything: `$ rake refinery:override view=refinery/pages/show` returns this `Could not find builder-3.0.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
`

Comment: I added a 3rd update above, but I'm wondering if this looks right to you: `$ which rvm` returns `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm`

Answer (score 1):

You installed RVM incorrectly, which is easy to do.  "This usually is because people execute the install as root, rather than executing the installation instructions from a non-privileged user account."  I suggest removing RVM entirely with `sudo rvm implode` and installing it again in single-user mode.  Run as you, not root, not sudo:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it looks like it installed it in root again. I added an new update above...

Comment: What was the result of `sudo rvm implode`?  You might have to more thoroughly remove rvm first.  See [How do I completely clean out all traces of RVM from my system, including for system wide installs?](https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting/)

Comment: I'll look at your link. When I did `sudo rvm implode` there was no message, so I assumed it worked. rails and other ruby commands didn't work. The only reason I was concerned was the path which looked like root again.

Comment: You are right to be concerned.  Ruby should be in `~/.rvm/rubies/`